# Maven Dependency to file in resources root folder

Tags: maven, dependencies

I got Java module and structure looks like:

```
moduleX
  -resources
   |-icons
     |_ icon.png
   |-libs
     |_ library.jar
  -src
pom.xml
```

`resources` is a folder mark as Resources Root in Intellij IDEA.

How should looks Maven dependency to get the `library.jar` ?

I tried as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>library</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/resources/libs/library.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

On OS X system works well but on Windows system do not work - do not find path.

Also I have set up a resources in `pom.xml`

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add local jar files in maven project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-in-maven-project)

Comment: Don't use `<scope>system</scope>`. Use the other answers in the linked question.

Comment: @Tunaki without `<scope>system</system>` maven do not want to build it.

Comment: There are other, better, and more supported, solutions. Install the file in your local repository with `mvn install:install-file`; or use a repository manager.

Comment: Maybe other what without install in local repository ? I checked solutions from there but I do not find correct answer for my problem

Comment: That _is_  the solution. Or you can use a file based repository, as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28762617/1743880.

Comment: Can You create example attached to my module structure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I utilize this approach on my project:

1. Create a repo folder under project:
   This folder is not necessarily marked as Resources root.
2. run maven command to install the jar file to local repo:

> ```
> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=[path to jar]/library.jar  -DlocalRepositoryPath=[path to repo]/repo/ -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=TestLibrary -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=1.0
> ```

3. Let maven recognize local repo:

> ```
> <repositories>
>     <repository>
>         <id>my-local-repo</id>
>         <url>file://${basedir}/../repo</url>
>     </repository>
> </repositories>
> ```

4. Reference in pom.xml:

> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>com.example</groupId>
>     <artifactId>TestLibrary</artifactId>
>     <version>1.0</version>
> </dependency>
> ```